# Wildcard for path to location on remote host

Tags: bash, wildcards, string

In Bash I need to check if the path contained in a string is pointing to a remote location or not. The following does does not work - `some code` does not get executed. It seems that I am missing something about how wildcards work with the `test` (`[`) command but I can't figure out what. The man page does not help me. What am I doing wrong and how should I be going about this instead?

```
path="user@host:/home/user"
if [ "$path" == ?*"@"?*":"?* ]; then
  some code
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[` command is a command and is parsed as any other command. That means that in:

```
[ "$path" == ?*"@"?*":"?* ]
```

The `?*"@"?*":"?*` is taken as a glob so would expand to the list of files in the current directory that match that pattern (just like `*.txt` expands to the list of `txt` files in the current directory).

Even if you wrote it:

```
[ "$path" == '?*@?*:?*' ]
```

to prevent the globbing, that wouldn't work as the `==` operator (non-standard version of `=`) of the `[` command is just a string equality operator, not a pattern matching one.

To do pattern matching, you can use the `ksh`-style `[[ x = pattern ]]` pattern-matching operator which `bash` and `zsh` also support:

```
path="user@host:/home/user"
if [[ "$path" = ?*@?*:* ]]; then
  some code
fi
```

Or better still, use the POSIX/Bourne `sh` `case` construct:

```
case $path in
  ?*@?*:*) some code
esac
```

This way, you don't even need to have `bash` installed, you can use you system's standard `sh` to interpret your script.

Note that `user@host:/home/user` is also a valid *local* path (try `mkdir -p user@host:/home/user`) though with `scp`, you'd need to pass it as `./user@host:/home/user` so that it be not treated as a remote path. So you may want to refine your test to:

```
case ${path%%@?*:*} in
  (*/* | "$path" | "") echo not a remote path;;
  (*) echo remote path;;
esac
```

So that `./x@y:z` be not treated as a remote path.

That's still not enough to do the same thing as `scp` does to decide whether a path is remote or not. Looking at [OpenSSH `scp` code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/ed877ef653847d056bb433975d731b7a1132a979/misc.c#L432), a path is remote if it doesn't start with `:` and if it contains a `:` with no `/` to the left of it and that is not inside a `[...]` (for IPv6 addresses like `[::1]`. Except that those `[...]` are only considered in host position (at the beginning or following a `@`). So for instance `x:`, `@:` are remote paths (though obviously the user and host part being empty, that will likely not work properly) and `user@[::1/64]:/x` (`/` left to the `:` that is not in between `[...]`) or `[foo@bar:/path` are local paths (the `:` is inside `[...]`).

Matching that with one POSIX `case` statement would be impossible. To match with one regular expression, it would be slightly easier with regular expressions that support look around operators like the `perl` ones. `zsh` and `ksh93` have support for those (`zsh` using the PCRE library, `ksh93` using its own implementation).

- `zsh`:

  ```
  set -o rematchpcre
  remote='^(?!:)(?:(?!\[)[^/:]*@)?(?:\[(?:(?!]:)[^/])*\]|(?!\[)[^/:]*):'
  if [[ $path =~ $remote ]]; then
    some code
  fi
  ```
- `ksh93`:

  ```
  remote='(?P:^(?!:)(?:(?!\[)[^/:]*@)?(?:\[(?:(?!]:)[^/])*\]|(?!\[)[^/:]*):)'
  if [[ $path =~ $remote ]]; then
    some code
  fi
  ```

(I wouldn't be surprised if that could be simplified).